# Text file encoding

Tags: macos, csv, encoding, utf-8

I'm having a problem trying to read in windows a CSV file generated in MAC.

My question is how can I convert the encoding to UTF-8 or even ISO-8859-1.

I've already tried iconv with no success.

Inside "vim" I can understand that in this file linebreaks are marked with ^M and the accent ã is marked with <8b>, Ç = <82> and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: besides encoding of line end `iconv` should do the trick. Can you give some information which encoding your input file uses?

Answer (score 1):

To convert from encoding a to encoding b, you need to know what encoding a is.

Given that

> ã is marked with <8b>, Ç = <82>

encoding a is very likely [Mac OS Roman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_Roman).

So call iconv with `macintosh`* as `from` argument, and `utf-8` as `to` argument.

*try `macroman`, `x-mac-roman` etc if `macintosh` is not found